# Axios and POST request to Zendesk API

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, zendesk-api

I'm trying a custom ticket form with the Zendesk API for end users. I followed [this tutorial](https://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/ticketing/managing-tickets/building-a-custom-ticket-form-with-the-zendesk-api/) but it uses Python whereas I use Node and React. I use Axios but I got an error response

`data: { error: "Couldn't authenticate you" }`

Here is my code

```
    var axios = require('axios');
    var config = {
      method: 'post',
      url:'https://subdomain.zendesk.com/api/v2/requests.json',
      headers: { 
        'content-type': 'application/json'
      },
      data:{'request':{'subject': 'test', 'comment': {'body': 'ceci est un test'}}},
      auth:('MY_EMAIL/token:_TOKEN'),
    };
    
    axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
      res.send(response.data);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set your token as header like so:

```
var axios = require('axios');

const token = '{base-64-encoded email_address/token:api_token}'

var config = {
  method: 'post',
  url:'https://subdomain.zendesk.com/api/v2/requests.json',
  headers: { 
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Basic ${token}` 
  },
  data:{'request':{'subject': 'test', 'comment': {'body': 'ceci est un test'}}}
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  res.send(response.data);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```